# How do you turn a single character from a character array into a string?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, character

I'm using this for loop to go through my array's individual characters from a string.

```
for(int i=0;i< array;i++){
```

I need to print the characters one by one using g.drawString. Therefor I need the character at position [i] in the array to be turned into a string. How do I do this?

Comment: If you want ot turn single character to string use character + "";

Comment: @AchintyaJha while this works, it is not recommended but a hack that may be quite inefficient.

Comment: what is array ? char[]?

Comment: I used char array [] = s.toCharArray(); to make an array of characters from a string.

Comment: @HG Use `s.substring(i, i+1)` instead of copying the string to a `char[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
String.valueOf(yourChar)
```

So your loop would be:

```
for(int i=0;i< array;i++){
 g.drawString(String.valueOf(yourString.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: This produces an error "no suitable method found for drawString(String)". Also I need to put coordinates for the string.

Comment: Note that `String.valueOf(yourString.charAt(i))` is an inefficient and unnecessary complex way of doing `yourString.substring(i, i+1)`.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse it is a very interesting statement. Why `valueOf` is less efficient then `substring`? Both of them construct new `String` object.

Comment: @Andremoniy it constructs a new `String` **wrapping a new `char[]`**, instead of a new `String` *reusing* the old `char[]`. So it's roughly twice as expensive.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse how it could **reuse** "`old char[]`"? It is impossible, because `old char[]` is part of whole array, so could not extract part of old array as separate array and said, that it is `old array`.

Comment: @Andremoniy at least some Java versions used to represent Strings as char[] + offset + length, to allow cheap substring operations without duplicating the character array. I'm not 100% sure about the current state for Oracle/OpenJDK Java 6/7/8.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse For Oracle Java, according to its sources, it is just: `this.value = Arrays.copyOfRange(value, offset, offset+count)`. So in any way it makes copy of sub-array.

Comment: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-May/010257.html This discussion indicates that sharing of the backing buffers was removed in 7u6.

Comment: @Andremoniy so in essence, use `substring` if you *want* a substring. Because then you get the optimizations of the latest JDK. Even if in JDK7u6 it was removed again, it could be coming back in JDK8 or JDK9.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Looks strange if they will return removed algorithm again. Furthermore, in context of discussed issue such optimizations sound ridiculous.

Comment: @Andremoniy Well, `substring()` is the straightforward solution which will get you whatever the Java developers consider to be the fastest. And it's not surprising that this changes as the Hotspot compiler becomes more advanced. A *lot* of optimizations that were useful in Java 1.0 are now unnnecessary. So use `substring`, it is the official Java API for exactly this task.

Answer (score 1):

It's just simple: `"" + array.charAt(i)`

Comment: Ouch. Have you ever profiled this, or checked what code it translates into?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse yeah, I know, it constructs new `String` object (JLS 15.18.1). I don't think that in particular this issue it will cause some serious performance troubles. What do you think?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse BTW `String.valueOf(char c)` also constructs new `String`.

Comment: It may just follow JLS 15.18.1.2, so in order to construct the String object, it builds a `StringBuilder` object first, then appends to this.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
char[] array;

g.drawString(String.valueOf(array[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best practice way:

```
char[] array;
for (char c : array) {
    String s = String.valueOf(c);
    // do something with s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the best way to do this is *if your source is a String*:

```
str.substring(i, i+1); // If you have a string.
```

**because it avoids unnecessary character buffer copies**. *Some* versions of Java (apparently JDK7u5 and earlier) can then *reuse the existing character buffer* and this way avoid an extra object creation.
(See: [this announcement of the change](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-May/010257.html), indicating that this holds for JDK7u5 and before)

There are two quite obvious alternatives (this one also works if you have your own `char[]` as data source):

```
String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)); // If you have a String
String.valueOf(chararray[i]); // If you have a char[]
```

These will actually create two objects: one `String` and one `char[1]`.

And then there is the ugly hackling:

```
"" + str.charAt(i); // If you do do not care about doing things right.
```

which usually causes the creation of a string buffer, with a single append operation, and the conversion to a string. If you use this code in a hot loop, it may really hurt your applications performance. While the code *looks* really simple, it supposedly translates to:

```
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuiler("");
temp.append(str.chatAt(i));
temp.toString();
```

And this overhead is actually quite useless, given that there are two clean solutions available in the API: converting characters to Strings, and constructing substrings.

Comment: who tells that aray is a String? it can be a char array

Comment: @AlexWien in that case, you can still resort to the second approach. However, if it is a string, one should use the first. It's a straightforward use of the API.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
char[] chars = {'a','b','c'};
    String[] strings = new String[chars.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        strings[i] = String.valueOf(chars[i]);
    }
```